# Include Redux Node Module In Webpack Build

Tags: javascript, webpack

My own modules get included in the build but when using a public node module it does not get included for some reason. Here is the code below.

```
import helloWorld from "./module";
import Redux from 'redux'

console.log(Redux)
console.log(helloWorld)
```

when I open the browser Redux is undefined but helloWorld works properly and has my object.

The question is, how can I include redux in my build.

Here is my simple WebPack Config

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure entity with name `Redux` exists in redux module.

Try `import { createStore } from 'redux'` instead. The set up looks fine.

Comment: It's way it is exported (https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/index.d.ts), so you can import only required fields and functions instead of importing entire library. Alternatively, you can do something like -  import * as redux from 'redux', but don't do this.

Comment: Thank you so much, i would of not known that if you didn't help me. I was banging my head on the wall for the past few hours as to why... Thanks again.